# SFML Can't Load Image

Tags: c++, visual-studio, sfml

I am trying to load an image with SFML, here is my code.

```
// Get the background texture
Texture bg;
if (!bg.loadFromFile("background.jpg"))
{
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
}

Sprite background;
background.setTexture(bg);
background.setPosition(width / 2, height / 2);
```

and in the main loop:

```
window.draw(background);
```

Now I have included the background.jpg in every single folder for this solution, starting from C:/users/username/source/repos/thisSolution. However I am still getting the failed to load image error, is there some arbitrary folder where VS2017 would be looking for this file?

Comment: Visual Studio by default sets the working directory to the output directory. Try putting it in the same folder as the built executable.

Comment: To further clarify, this folder will probably be called `Debug` or `Release`, depending on your configuration. If you are building inside VS, then I believe the resources should go in the same folder as the `.vcxproj`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [I can not open and image using the SFML library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54853838/i-can-not-open-and-image-using-the-sfml-library)

Answer (score 0):

As [@Arnav Broborah](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6525260/arnav-borborah) pointed, by default with Visual Studio, resources should be located into your project folder (where `.vcxproj` file is)

If you have created your project with "Create directory for solution", the 
resulting hierarchy will be something like:

`C:\Users\username\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\YourSolution\YourProject`

Obviously, those names depends on the drive you installed VS, username, VS version, etc, but your **resource files should go into the project folder** by default.

Answer (score 0):

You can change it in debug settings

[image]